# Responsive css button with background-image

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I achieve a responsive button that contains a background-image.
It is something like http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-responsive-pagination/full_screen_preview/4266559
However, in my case the "prev" and "next" button is a really long text and in the center is just "title" of the page.

Having a hard time scaling the background-image to make sure it fits into the scaled button and works on IE.

Has anyone ever done this before?
Is it even possible?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: You've given us a link to what is similar, but would you be able to show us the actual issue itself? Maybe give the code in a jsfiddle/codepen (and a screenshot of the problem). It would help us understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If your target browser support CSS3, simply use background-size

```
.button
{
background:url(img_flwr.gif);
background-size:contain contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Edit:
As you need to support IE8 and below,
you might try:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../background.png', sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../background.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

or  dl ie-css3.htc and:

```
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work on IE as they don't support background-size.

Comment: [It most certainly does since IE9](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts). Also, instead of `background-size:contain contain` I'd recommend writing `background-size:contain` since its whole point is to maintain aspect ratio - specifying it separately for width and height seems overly confusing. Just a style preference though.

Comment: Apologise, I thought it was only 10+, but since @teepusink didn't specify the version of IE I assumed he meant further than 9 or 10.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes Yes, contain is better than contain contain. But I want to show that there can be width and height 2 parameters